# dispatch() method in class-based components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to React/Redux binding and I`m gonna implement Redux component with form that refresh jokes with possibility of changing quantity of fetched jokes (1 joke by default):

```
      import fetchJokes from '../actions/jokes';
      import { connect } from 'react-redux';

      class FormToRefresh extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {value: 1};
          this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
          this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        }

        handleInput(e) {
          let input = e.target.value;
          if(isNaN(input)||input > 10||input< 1) {
            alert("Wrong input");
            this.setState({value: 1}); 
          } else {
            this.setState({value: input})     
          }

          handleSubmit(e) {
            // this should trigger dispatching fetchJokes action
            // but how to integrate dispatch() function here...                

            dispatch(fetchJokes(this.state.value));

          }

          render() {
            return (
              <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit>
                  <label>Enter amount of jokes (from 1 to 10):
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onInput={this.handleInput} />
                  </label>
                  <button type="submit">Refresh</button>
                </form>  
              </div>)
            } 
          }

         export default connect()(FormToRefresh);
```

Generally, I look up into guide https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#implementing-other-components , I tend to implement class-based component rather than function-based. I have some misunderstanding of how *dispatch()* method was integrated into guide`s AddTodo function and how should I implement it in my FormToRefresh class? If you notice any other mistake, please, let me know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you don't pass `mapDispatchToProps`, the connect function makes `dispatch` available as prop to the component and hence you can make use of that

```
// bind the below function 
handleSubmit  = (e)  => { 
    const { dispatch } = this.props;                
    dispatch(fetchJokes(this.state.value));
}
```

or

pass the action to connect like

```
// bind the below function 
handleSubmit  = (e)  => { 
    const { fetchJokes } = this.props;                
    fetchJokes(this.state.value);
}

export default connect(null, { fetchJokes })(FormToRefresh);
```

Comment: As far as I know I can call `store.dispach()` where `store = createStore(mainReducer)` ,but how it get available in component`s props?

Comment: connect passes it as props to the component